# Python Selenium find placeholder if it contains

Tags: python, selenium

At the moment my code is

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='phone']").send_keys('000000000000')
```

How would I make it so it would find the placeholder if it contained the word "phone", not just finding the exact word like it is at the moment?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `contains()` function to check if the `placeholder` attribute **contains** the word `"phone"`:

#### Code:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@placeholder, 'phone')]").send_keys('000000000000')
```

This will find any input elements with a placeholder attribute that contains the word "phone", rather than just matching the exact string "phone".